# When is it valid to pass a pointer out of a function?

Tags: c

I'm wrestling with the minutiae of variable lifetimes in C (of course)!

I've learnt that I shouldn't leave variables that were defined within functions floating around, expect when the memory for that variable has been allocated with `malloc`. What I can't work out is how I know when a pointer is good to pass out of a function.

In the following example, there is a fundamental difference between `fptr` and `p_uniqueId`:

```c
int initialize_db(ToyDatabase* p_tdb, const char* filePath) {
    
    FILE* fptr;
    if ((fptr = fopen(filePath, "wb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error! opening file");
        return -1;
    }
    int uniqueId = 2;
    int* p_uniqueId = &uniqueId; 
    p_tdb->pFile = fptr;  //Presumably not a dangling pointer, how to tell?
    p_tdb->pId = p_uniqueId; //Will become a dangling pointer, not Ok!
    return 0;
}

int cleanup(ToyDatabase* p_tdb)
{
    fclose(p_tdb->fptr);
    //Do I need to do anything else with this fptr? Maybe p_tdb->fptr = NULL;????

    return 0;
}
```

In the example, the address pointed to by `p_tdb->pId` won't be valid outside the `initialize_db` function. But presumably `p_tdb->pFile` will be valid, presumably because `fopen` allocated memory for `fptr`.

Is there something in the documentation for `fopen` that I'm looking for that delineates these two cases, or is it just assumed that any function returning a pointer has been `malloc`d?

Comment: Unless a function's documentation *explicitly* states that you need to `free` the pointed to object, you should never attempt to do so. Since `fopen` doesn't say anything about that, you don't have to worry about it. Also setting a pointer to `NULL` has absolutely no effect on the memory it refers to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `p_uniqueId` unambiguously points to `uniqueId` which has automatic storage class. If it were a global, malloc'd, static, etc then you'd be fine.

> Is there something in the documentation for fopen that I'm looking for that delineates these two cases, or is it just assumed that any function returning a pointer has been mallocd?

The [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) doesn't say much. It just says that a `FILE*` is returned, which you can safely use and pass around. It might not have been necessarily malloc'd, as it could have been allocated in a static buffer or other implementation-dependent storage. You thus can't assume that it can be safely `free`d. At best you leave a dangling file descriptor because `free` doesn't know anything about file streams.

The only remarks about cleanup that I found were in the `fclose` manpage:

> [after calling `fclose`]... any further access (including another call to fclose()) to the
> stream results in undefined behavior.

> `//Do I need to do anything else with this fptr? Maybe p_tdb->fptr = NULL;????`

You don't *need* to do anything, per se. You can leave `p_tdb->fptr` dangling with the understanding that using it is UB. You could null it. You could replace it with a different file pointer. By setting it to NULL, you can detect that it doesn't point anywhere meaningful using a null-check. If you don't check it, it's just as harmful to use (UB wise) after being nulled as if you used it while it was dangling.

Comment: Ok. So as I understand it, to paraphrase the manpage, the very fact that `fopen` returns `FILE*` means this pointer must be valid outside `fopen`. Otherwise, it wouldn't be a very helpful function :) So pass it around.

Comment: @StephenEllis Essentially. Sometimes, further notes may be given about the validity of a pointer, e.g. [`readdir`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) mentions that subsequent readdir calls can overwrite the returned object.